# module 'ssl' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1

Tags: ssl, jira-rest-api

Trying to access jira using rest API but getting SSL error,

```
url = "https://URL/rest/api/2/issue/"+issueId
resposnsenew=requests.request("GET",url, auth=('xya','Makkfafdk@##5'))

File "D:\RestJIRA\restjiravenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 82, in <module>
    ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD,
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1'
```

Any idea how to solve the issue?